# Error: 0x80072746 The connection to sandbox was lost

Tags: windows-10, sandbox

Please visit to [my original post here](https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/133102-error-0x80072746-connection-sandbox-lost.html).

I updated laptop to Windows 10 Home Edition 1903. Using this tutorial: [Enable Windows Sandbox Feature in Windows 10 Home Edition](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/131437-enable-windows-sandbox-feature-windows-10-home-edition.html) I enabled Windows Sandbox on my Windows 10 Home, but it's failing to start.

I got this error:

[image: error]

Comment: EDIT: added tutorial link

Comment: I see you've posted the same question here https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/error-0x80072746-the-connection-to-sandbox-was-lost.196299/#post-1189419 and here https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/133102-error-0x80072746-connection-sandbox-lost.html#post1638655, are you waiting to see which users respond first?

Comment: well yes I have posted same question here too. But it wasn't so get the fast reply. I just wanted to look at other options about this error (if) can be.
Btw I haven't published this on windowsphoneinfo site. ( i literally wonder this thing)

the original Q by me is on superuser & tenforums only. !

Comment: If you are here to look for solution, you may visit my original post here 
https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/133102-error-0x80072746-connection-sandbox-lost.html

I will make update about the issue on my original post. Presumably many other people are having same issue. Kindly wait for the solution or You may just upgrade to Windows 10 Pro.

:)

Comment: I too am facing the same issue!! Hope that upgrading to pro is not the only option!!

Comment: Same issue on a PRO version

Comment: I am getting this same error on Windows 11 ENTERPRISE. Did anyone ever figure out how to fix this?