# I tried to install windows sandbox on windows 11 home, when I open it it says "Windows sandbox failed to initialize" (no error codes)

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, windows-11, windows-sandbox

First, I tried to disable the sandbox and then reactivate later using these commands:

```
Dism /online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:"Containers-DisposableClientVM"
Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:"Containers-DisposableClientVM"
```

But as you can imagine, it didn't work out.

For info here is the command I used to install the sandbox on windows home

```
echo off pushd "%~dp0"
dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\*Containers*.mum >List.txt
for /f %i in ('findstr /i . List.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%i"
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Containers-DisposableClientVM -All /LimitAccess /ALL
pause
```

Thanks to everyone who is trying to solve my problem.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Windows Sandbox cannot be installed on Windows 11 Home.  The command you used, didn't work for Windows 10 Home, and it still doesn't work for Windows 11 Home. It never actually worked.  If you are looking to undo the damage the command did you are looking at performing a Reset to do that[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1548379/running-sandbox-on-window-10-home-error-0x80072746-the-connection-to-sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

> "I tried to install Windows Sandbox on Windows 11 Home"

You should also know that Windows Sandbox doesn’t work in the Home editions of Windows 11, but it is included in the Pro and Enterprise versions.

[Windows 11 Sandbox](https://windowsreport.com/windows-sandbox-windows-11/)

> ...   In technical terms, it is a virtual machine designed on-demand,
> by using Microsoft’s hypervisor and running the same operating system
> screen as the one on your first machine.
>
> It is around 100MB in size which can be used to install and run
> untrusted classic apps, in an isolated mode from the main
> installation.  ....

.

You can upgrade to Pro if you need Sandbox